# How do you return a certain value based on whether a certain date has passed in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

So I have sort of a complicated question that I have been working on for awhile now. So what I am trying to do is return a specific value when a list of dates reaches a **date that is *greater than or equal* to a specified date**. In other words I want this certain calculated value to appear once a certain date is reached or a date past the specified date is input into the row of cells that track the dates.

My dates start in A2 and the specified date in this case is F5 which is equal to 1/15/2020. The value to return let’s say is the formula H2*12.5 if the date is reached or passed. Otherwise I would like the cell to remain empty. So far I have tried this formula:

"=IF(IFNA(FILTER($A$2:$A$35, $A$2:$A$35>=F5),””)>=F5, H2*12.5,””)" however this is not properly tracking correctly I would really love some help with this one, I am stumped.

Thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding out the correct formula to use and answered my own question. The formula that I was looking for was an `IF statement`.

> =IF(COUNT(FILTER($A$2:$A,$A$2:$A >=F5))>=1,H2*12.5,"")

This formula was able to do exactly what I was looking for which was if a date was exactly or beyond the specified date in F5 then it would return the value of H2*12.5 and if the date was not past that then the cell would remain blank.

If you want to see what I have done I have attached the solution sheet which you can copy and keep for your own records if you have any use for this formula.
[Returning certain value based on specified date](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eDTEhIpGPRB4rFvmAPoJdozIB36YG5Amui7leqsa6YQ/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Great! You have figured it out. You may further go for a simpler/sorter formula here `if(COUNTIF(A2:A19,">="&F5)>0,H2*12.5,"")`

Comment: @BHAWANI SINGH Yes thank you for all of your help and thank you for the shortened formula as well I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the required result can be easily achieved with `arrayformula`

> =arrayformula(if(A2:A35>=F5,H2*12.5,""))

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried that but unfortunately was unsuccessful. The goal is to return one cell either the "H2*12.5" or the "" based on whether a date in the date column is equal to or greater than F5 (1/15/2020). When I put it in the if statement it returns false even if there is a date in the column that is equal to or greater than 1/15/2020.

Comment: @Foxxsheets66 I am not sure, how that could happen. It should have worked as in the screenshot attached with the answer.

Comment: @Foxxsheets66 can you please check the `formatting` of your range **A2:A35** and Cell **F5** , and confirm it's not set to text.

Comment: @Foxxsheets66 please share the sample google sheet, if it's possible

Comment: @BHAWNI SINGH  Thank you so much for your help and for your responses I really appreciate it. However, it seems that I have finally figured it out and answered my own question.